# JSON schema definitions validation for internal reference

Tags: node.js, jsonschema, ajv

I am creating thousands of definitions and making it available on remote so that any one can reuse the defined schema by referring remote ref. at the time of definition creation i want something which can check the $ref and throw error if it is not available

```
{
      "definitions":{
        "description100Type":{
          "$ref":"#/definitions/additinalType"
        }
      },
      "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "$id":"http://example.com/root.json"

    }
```

In the above example **description100Type** referring **additinalType** which was not defined.
How to validate the above case ? i am using [ajv](https://ajv.js.org) for validations.

note:ajv is throwing proper error if description100Type is referred inside *properties*

```
{
  "properties":{
    "checked":{
      "$id":"#/properties/checked",
      "$ref":"#/definitions/description100Type"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The schema you have currently provided does not make sense or is not complete. Can you please provide your complete schema, or explain what you think it should do? The error is correct. What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: I just need to validate definitions part present in JSON schema

Comment: I'm sorry, I still do not understand what you want to do, because what you are asking to do does not make sense. Can you start again, and modify your question to explain what you are doing and what you expect to happen please?

Comment: The JSON Schema you have provided includes a reference to another schema, which you haven't included in the provided schema. In addition you do not reference the definition you have provided anywhere. Did you write this schema or was it provided for you?

Comment: if anything inside definitions (like description100Type) referring another definitions (#/definitions/additinalType) which is not present then the error like :Can't resolve reference #/definitions/additinalType

Comment: That is correct. I think you may need to check you have a correct understanding of `$ref` and `definitions`: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#reuse

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 
I am creating thousands of definitions and making it available on remote so that any one can reuse the defined schema by referring remote ref.
at the time of definition creation i want something which can check the $ref and throw error if it is not availble

Comment: OK. Please take a moment to read the StackOverflow guide on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186351/discussion-between-monica-garud-and-relequestual).